# TempData funciona no Localhost mas não funciona quando publicado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Agradeço desde já a atenção!

Estou desenvolvendo em ASP.NET MVC5

O que acontece é o seguinte: quando realizado os testes no *localhost*, este código funciona perfeitamente. Eu consigo recuperar o `tempdata` contendo o objeto para enviá-lo para a *View* que gera o PDF. Porém, quando eu publico o projeto em um servidor de homologação, a chamada para o *Controller* `BAIXARPDF` não consegue receber a `tempdata`, ela fica nula. Alguém pode me dar uma idéia do porquê do comportamento diferente nos ambientes?

Faço a seguinte chamada Ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            url:urlL,
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(UniformePDF),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (iddata) {
                window.location = iddata;
                baixarPDF(iddata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                alert(err);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
```

Essa chamada chama a seguinte *Action* no *Controller*:

```
    public ActionResult GerarPDF(UniformePDF u)
    {
        TempData["teste"] = "teste";

        if (u.NomePeca == null)
        {
            u.NomePeca = "padrao";
        }

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
            ViewBag.UniformeBag = u;
            TempData[u.NomePeca] = u;
            TempData.Keep(u.NomePeca);
           //string url =  RedirectToAction("BaixarPDF", "Uniforme", new { UniformePDF = u, area = "Uniformes"})
           string url = urlHelper.Action("baixarPDF", new { idUniforme = u.NomePeca });
            return Json(url, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Esse *Controller* monta um `tempdata` e retorna um Json com a URL para o próximo *Controller* que irá recuperar o objeto dentro do `tempdata` e retornar uma *View* que gera um PDF.

```
  public ActionResult baixarPDF(string idUni)
  {
       bool retorno = false;
       String remover, link, adicionar;
       UniformePDF modeloUniforme = new UniformePDF();

       if (TempData["teste"] != null)
       {
           modeloUniforme = TempData[Request.QueryString["idUniforme"]] as UniformePDF;
           if (modeloUniforme.NomePeca == Request.QueryString["idUniforme"])
           {
               //var svg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
               remover = getBetween(modeloUniforme.Desenho, "<svg", "<g");
               link = "http:" + "//www.w3.org/2000/svg";
               adicionar = "<svg xmlns=\"" + link + "\" width=\"500px\" height=\"500px\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\">";
               if (remover.Length != 0)
               {
                    modeloUniforme.Desenho = modeloUniforme.Desenho.Replace(remover, adicionar);
               }

               string svgString = modeloUniforme.Desenho;
               string base64 = CreateBase64Image(svgString);
               modeloUniforme.DirBase64 = base64;
                retorno = true;
            }
        }
       if (retorno)
       {
           return new PartialViewAsPdf("Modelo", modeloUniforme)
           {
               PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
               FileName = modeloUniforme.NomePeca + ".pdf"
           };
       }
       else
       {
           return Json(retorno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
    }
```

Comment: No **console** do browser você recebe algum erro ao chamar a consulta `ajax`?
Qual o valor que está sendo passado na `urlL`?

Answer (score 1):

Esta é a maneira mais errada de se fazer. Em primeiro lugar, não há a necessidade da separação do código desta forma, até porque cada *Action* de um *Controller* necessariamente precisa devolver um resultado concreto. Você montou uma *Action* que não funciona sozinha, e que depende de outra pra devolver algo desejado.

Em segundo lugar, não é pra isso que `TempData` serve. Ele guarda algumas informações que podem ser úteis para a construção de uma *View*, e apenas isso. Não serve para montar PDFs e coisas do tipo.

Em terceiro lugar, usar Ajax para devolver um arquivo **é totalmente errado**. Não faço ideia do porquê você está fazendo assim, mas Ajax não manipula esse tipo de requisição. O correto é usar uma requisição normal e fazer seu *Controller* devolver um `FileResult`.

---

Às alterações.

Primeiro, `GerarPDF` pode ser inteiro jogado fora. Tudo o que ele faz no contexto do que você precisa é inútil.

Segundo, altere seu método `BaixarPDF` para o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BaixarPDF(UniformePDF uniforme)
{
    // Retirei essas variáveis daqui. Essa declaração não tem necessidade.
    // String remover, link, adicionar;

    //var svg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    var remover = getBetween(uniforme.Desenho, "<svg", "<g");
    var link = "http:" + "//www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var adicionar = "<svg xmlns=\"" + link + "\" width=\"500px\" height=\"500px\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\">";

    if (remover.Length != 0)
    {
        uniforme.Desenho = uniforme.Desenho.Replace(remover, adicionar);
    }

    var svgString = modeloUniforme.Desenho;
    var base64 = CreateBase64Image(svgString);
    modeloUniforme.DirBase64 = base64;

    return new PartialViewAsPdf("Modelo", modeloUniforme)
    {
        PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
        FileName = modeloUniforme.NomePeca + ".pdf"
    };
}
```

Como você está usando Rotativa, use o `ActionResult` porque o MVC terá que gerar a *View* pra você. `FileResult` seria para o caso em que o PDF é montado em *Controller*.

Comment: Cigano, muito obrigado pela sua explicação, eu realizei uma chamada ajax para gerar o pdf pois precisava manter o estado da página estático, foi uma forma "engambiarrada" para resolver o problema, o caso era que funcionava normal, eu realizava a chamada com o ajax para montar um objeto com dados que são construídos dentro de um SVG. eu tinha que montar um objeto e enviar para um controller, e salvei os objetos dentro da TEMP, pois foi o unico modo que enxerguei para guardar o objeto contruido para enviar para o rotativa